# ng-oidc-client: clientSettings.userStore is not a function

Tags: angular, authentication, openid-connect

While following [this](https://medium.com/interoperable/securing-your-angular-7-application-with-oidc-and-ngrx-7775e8325b51) setup guide I get `clientSettings.userStore is not a function` when loading the page.

I've copied the oidc_config object, and simply changed the authority:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
    oidc_config: {
        authority: 'http://localhost:49853/',
        client_id: 'ng-oidc-client-identity',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49853/callback.html',
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        scope: 'openid profile offline_access api1',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49853/signout-callback.html',
        silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49853/renew-callback.html',
        accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
    },
    log: {
        logger: console,
        level: Log.NONE
    }
})
```

And added the corresponding asset files:

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/static",
        "output": "/"
      },
      {
        "glob": "oidc-client.min.js",
        "input": "node_modules/oidc-client/dist",
        "output": "/"
      }
    ],
```

versions:

```
"@ngrx/effects": "7.4.0",
"@ngrx/store": "7.4.0",
"ng-oidc-client": "1.0.5",
"oidc-client": "^1.9.1"
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hkwrr?file=package.json)

I've tried tinkering with the versioning, as I'm running Angular 7, but npm by default installs dependencies on 8. However nothing seems to be working so far.

Comment: Please put any relevant code in the question. A StackBlitz is great! But not what works best for a QA

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the code with relevant code. Since the question seems to be about setup I assumed a stackblitz would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the userstore as a function like this.

```js
export function getWebStorageStateStore() {
  return new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage });
}

NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
    oidc_config: {
        authority: 'http://localhost:49853/',
        client_id: 'ng-oidc-client-identity',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49853/callback.html',
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        scope: 'openid profile offline_access api1',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49853/signout-callback.html',
        silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:49853/renew-callback.html',
        accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        userStore: getWebStorageStateStore
    },
    log: {
        logger: console,
        level: Log.NONE
    }
}
```